# A Japanese old novel about a kid who enters a magical/horror forest/hill at night and everything's different from the day?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I don't really recall much of the book, just that I was so in awe of it and could possibly feel the way I felt when I read it the first time. Especially the forest/hill scenes. I think in the forest/hill, the dead comes back to life? One day, the kid (a girl I think) who lives in a small village nearby, goes to the forest/hill at night for something I don't really recall. There is a bridge that connects the village and the forest/hill. She has to go back to the village before the sunrise.

I am eighteen now and I was in elementary school when I first read it (around 2010-2012) so it might be a very old novel. It's by a Japanese author and not part of any series. I read it in Bahasa. The overal theme I remember is kind of a mix between horror, mystery, and adventure. Of course there are fantasy and folklore as well.

Comment: You've provided some details but every little bit helps, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: There is a book called, **To the Fireworks Forest**, which was written by a japanese author, Yuki Midori-kawa. The book was first published in July 2002, originally having a Japanese name, but I speak Japa-nese, and so I translated it to the title in bold. The main character is a girl called *Hotaru* who gets lost in an enchanted forest, meeting a young boy called *Gin*. There has been a movie based on this, known as **Into the Forest of Fireflies' Light** which was made in 2011. Is this the book you might be talking about?

Comment: @user477344 I don't think it's the right novel. Maybe take a look at the new edit for a bit you have any other book in mind? I don't really remember much so I'm sorry for the small details I could only provide.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thank you for the suggestion. I have added some minor details. Sadly, I cant add more.

Comment: Nah it's alright. That's what we're here for anyway, to answer problems like these. It's more of a challenge when the details are less clear :) ..... Also, by the way, this book you are talking about appears to be quite similar to the 1994 Disney animated movie, **The Swan Princess**.